Cannot connect to Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 24.04 Raspberry Pi 4
My issue: I cannot connect to Ubuntu via Remote Desktop and get rejected with error code: 0x207, which means password expired.
The system: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.
The network: just my home and my local network. The pi is not accessible from outside.
The context: I am [trying so far] using MacOS and Android's Microsoft RDP client to access the Pi4.
I have already enabled Remote Desktop and setup user and password in Ubuntu's settings.
I know that the password get regenerated every time I login again due to keyring issue so I double check the id and password before I try.
But each and every time Ubuntu refuse the connection and issue an error code 0x207.
If I use Microsoft RDP client app on Android table to login, I see a Ubuntu login screen with the user in the middle and big Ubuntu icon at the bottom of the screen. The screen is NOT interactive however so I couldn't login. However, it does demonstrate that the connection is established before user authentication at the least.
I have searched for answers and to my surprise there are so many people having similar problem but yet to find any real solution.
But since I get a login screen with my Android Tablet and with an 0x207 error, the issue my be related to user and password. But obviously I have no idea what else to try.
Please help.

try ''remmina''

I also disabled the native solution and installed xrdp with success. It complained about not being secure because it didn't have access to a TLS key. The solution is here:
sudo chmod 644 /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
sudo chmod 640 /etc/xrdp/key.pem
sudo chown :xrdp /etc/xrdp/key.pem
sudo systemctl restart xrdp

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2297

For me on the target PC I edited the login details at the bottom of the Remote Login screen in System -> Remote Desktop and used those login details from another PC's RDP client.
Target PC:


I wasn't able to make remote login work at all with the built-in remote feature, so my solution is to use XRDP.

Disable the toggles on both the Desktop Sharing and Remote Login tabs
Restart the machine
Run sudo apt install xrdp

Now you should be able to connect and log in while not being logged in locally.
One difference is that it works the same way RDP does on windows, which means you cannot be logged in both locally and remotely at the same time. If you need to do that, you may try enabling the Desktop Sharing tab, setting a different port like 3390, and then potentially wrestling with keyrings.

My objective is just to remove control my remote session so I don't need to walk over to the other room where the Pi is located. I suppose this is not exactly Remote Desktop Login but more of a VNC connection.
